# Use External Id in cross-account role of AWS using Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

Here is the problem: I need to use the Lambda function in AWS Account A (In root AWS Account A) to write some data to the DynamoDB tables in AWS Account B (in root AWS Account B). All the project in written with Serverless Framework in Node.js.

I know I need to use Cross-Account Role in the Lambda function to do that. Since Serverless use the template that shares a lot of things similar to the cloudformation template. Then I did some research on how to use the cross account role, here is the AWS Documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Principal": {"AWS": "Example Corp's AWS Account ID"},
    "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"sts:ExternalId": "12345"}}
  }
}
```

this is the sample iam specification for the task like this. The yaml template in the serverless looks like this in my project:

```
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal: 
        AWS: 'AWS Account B External ID'
      Action:
        - sts:AssumeRole
      Resource:
        - '*'
```

But When I tried to deploy the serverless template:
I got the error like this:

> An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Policy document should not specify a principal. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX).

I am wondering what is the correct way to specify the template according to the demand. 
Appreciate to the help of any kinds

Answer (score 0):

You can allow for assumed roles using an external ID by creating an `AWS::IAM:Role` resource. The example below gives access to an S3 bucket, but the approach is the same.

```
ExternalS3AccessRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    RoleName: SomeRoleName
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Principal:
            AWS: "Example Corp's AWS Account ID"
          Condition:
            StringEquals:
              'sts:ExternalId': "12345"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: ExternalS3AccessPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - s3:Get*
                - s3:List*
              Resource:
                - "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - s3:Get*
                - s3:List*
              Resource:
                - "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>"
```